# Plotting 3d Implicit equation with vispy

Tags: python, 3d, mayavi, vispy

Due to server `GPU` limitations we cannot use K to render implicit equations on the `VPS`, here's an example code we use to produce 3D models from equations in `mayavi`:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

mlab.clf()
x, y, z = np.mgrid[-2.5:2.5:.125, -2.5:2.5:.125, -2.5:2.5:.125]
a,b,c = 0.0,-5.0,11.8
values = x**4+y**4+z**4+a*(x**2+y**2+z**2)**2+b*(x**2+y**2+z**2)+c
mlab.contour3d(x, y, z, values, contours=[0], color=(.1,1,.5))

mlab.savefig("shape.obj")
```

This outputs this shape in 3D

[image: 3d equation rendered by mayavi]

My question is, how can I accomplish the same thing with `vispy` or another python module (if there exists)

We do not have graphics card on `VPS`, we're using python 3.5.1 (anaconda) on windows server 2008 (not possible to use linux) and we have replaced `opengl32.dll` with mesa in system32 (GL version 3.0 mesa 10.2.8)(VTK throws error GL Version 2.1 with the `gpu_shader4` extension is not supported...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer to my question, this is how it's done with vispy:

```
import numpy as np

from vispy import io
from vispy.geometry.isosurface import isosurface

x, y, z = np.mgrid[-2.5:2.5:.125, -2.5:2.5:.125, -2.5:2.5:.125]
a,b,c = 0.0,-5.0,11.8
data = x**4+y**4+z**4+a*(x**2+y**2+z**2)**2+b*(x**2+y**2+z**2)+c
vertices, faces = isosurface(data, level=1/10000000.)
io.write_mesh('shape.obj', vertices, faces , None, None, overwrite=True)
```

Exports a wavefront obj file exactly like the shape above. This is much faster than using mayavi.